# In Jmeter variable value is getting overridden with next thread value

Tags: performance, jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-5.0

I´m working on a JMeter testplan which is meant to preformance-test a webservice. The main part of the whole testplan consists of two steps.

1. Create one of these asset ID (via Post-request) - extracting asset ID by JSON extractor and setting variable using bean shell assertion ${__setProperty(assetId,${assetId})}
2. Delete created asset by ID (Delete request) - ${__property(assetId)}

If I use a singlethreaded plan, everything works out as expected, but as soon as I use more than one thread, then assetId will have last thread value and remaining values will be missed out. Could you please let me know how I can access/store all assetId in delete call

Comment: Please use variables instead of properties. Properties are shared with all threads. Variables are local to the threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads**, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

You should use the variable name of your JSON extractor instead of creating a property to avoid sharing the variable between threads.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the same property by each consecutive thread, you need to do something like:

1. In the first step change your code to:

   ```
   props.put("assetId_" + ctx.getThreadNum(), vars.get("assetId"));
   ```
2. In the second step use the [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) to read the property value:

   ```
   ${__groovy(props.get("assetId_" + ctx.getThreadNum()),)}
   ```

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to [JSR223 Assertion with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial/).